# How to make coordinates grid in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

I want to divide a container(or suitable widget) into 10x10 boxes and map them by coordinates like
(1,1),(1,2)....(10,10), so that I can move some widget to the specified box. Basically, like pieces move in ludo or chess. What is the best way to do this? I tried to use variable offset in Transform widget that is very tricky. Can you suggest something better pls?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) widget that allows creating elements that are scrollable and go multiple columns and rows.